# Manipulate Referenced Object

Tags: c#

Is there a way that I can pass in a reference to an object, manipulate it inside my method which directly changes the referenced object?

For instance I want to pass a dropdownlist into my method, manipulate it and be done.  This method is going to take in any dropdownlist:

```
public static void MyMethod(Dropdownlist list1, ref DropdownList list2)
{
    // just manipulate the dropdown here... no need to returnit.  Just Add or remove some values from the list2
}
```

obviously I can't just pass a dropdownlist object to list2.  So how can I do this?  I am going to remove some values in the list.  And this will be a nice utility method so I don't have to repeat this code all over the place for this functionality that I'm going to be performing in the method.

Comment: The way to remember this is that a "ref" or "out" parameter is actually a reference to a *variable*, not a reference to an *object*. That is, when you have a method M(ref int y) and you call it M(ref x), what you are saying is "y is now an alias for variable x".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are manipulating the internal data on a single reference type then you don't need anything special on the method signature.  When passing an object which is a reference type to a method you do not pass a copy.  Instead you pass a reference to the object.  Manipulating this reference will change the original object.

```
void MyMethod(List<string> list) {
  list.Add("foo");
}

void Example() {
  List<string> l = new List<sting>();
  MyMethod(l);
  Console.WriteLine(l.Count);  // Prints 1
  MyMethod(l);
  Console.WriteLine(l.Count);  // Prints 2
}
```

Now if you want to change where the original reference points to, you'll need a ref modifier.

Answer (score 2):

`DropDownList` is a reference type, so you should just be able to pass an instance into your method and manipulate it. (The object referenced inside your method *is* the original instance.)

You don't even need to specify the `ref` modifier so long as you're only updating the existing object, rather than replacing it.